# Making View in Big Query is good practice?

Tags: analytics, google-bigquery

I am making View in Big Query 
but if am running any query again on this View it says this query will process the same GB space as of the table whose Desired View is created

Does View Destroyed Automatically or we have to delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Views act in a similar way to macros: They auto-expand at execution time.

Storing a view processes no data: It just stores the associated query with a name you can use later.

When using a view in a larger query it will process data online: BigQuery has no materialized views (yet).

Comment: Sir Thankyou.. Here I have to make two view i.e smaller table from one big table its space would be less than 80% of original size table.. so i am thinking whether i should make a new table and delete it later or just work with view only because google big query cost on the size of table we run query

Comment: For cost savings: extract a new table :)

Answer (score 0):

Database views are immaterial. If you are looking for a logical layer, you are almost always better off doing the modeling in a tool such as Looker or Microstrategy, where you can document the view logic as well:
https://discourse.looker.com/t/how-to-reference-views-and-fields-in-lookml/179